# Avoiding line length to become zero

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to draw a line.

Has anybody developed a graphical environment and knows how to avoid NaN values when the line length becomes zero?

In a 2D environment the user might move a line or resize it... I'm having a problem in this area when during runtime the length becomes invalid leading the shape to disappear or behave abnormally such as turning into a point.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: I don't think you asked a question.

Comment: But a line of length 0 is effectively a point!  What would you expect?

Comment: At least instead of being quite and keep adding negative scores (which is not helpful), can you refer me to other forums that I can ask this problem? I mean forcing people not to talk is one thing but asking to share my issue in a different forum is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). For example, this pseudocode doesn't use division so it cannot result in NaN's: (from Wikipedia)

```
 function line(x0, y0, x1, y1)
   dx := abs(x1-x0)
   dy := abs(y1-y0) 
   if x0 < x1 then sx := 1 else sx := -1
   if y0 < y1 then sy := 1 else sy := -1
   err := dx-dy

   loop
     setPixel(x0,y0)
     if x0 = x1 and y0 = y1 exit loop
     e2 := 2*err
     if e2 > -dy then 
       err := err - dy
       x0 := x0 + sx
     end if
     if e2 <  dx then 
       err := err + dx
       y0 := y0 + sy 
     end if
   end loop
```

It will also draw a line where the start and end point at at the same coordinates. Depending on your definition, this is a line with a length of 0 or 1.

Comment: Another problem can be in that vectors need normalization after rotation, otherwise they may keep shrinking little by little with every rotation until that becomes visible.

Comment: Hi Virtlink, thanks for the link and example. However, this algorithm is used to draw a line segment where 2 end points are given. In my case, we are using built-in DrawLine method which Windows API provides.
The issue occur when both Start and End points are same and then after calculations return NaN.  So how it can this be useful the start and end points that we are using is already became NaN ?